# Symfony2: calling a function of another controller

Tags: php, symfony

The directory structure is

```
AppBundle/api/CartController
```

There is a function defined in `CartController.php` as `onlinecoupontrancation($params)`.

I need to call this function from `AppBundle/api/MerchantController.php`.
I tried

```
$this->forward('AppBundle:api/Cart:onlinecoupontrancation', $param);
```

But it is giving error 404. Any clue for this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is a shared function between two controllers, why not create a shared service class that both controllers use?

For example, CartFunctions.php

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Classes/CartFunctions.php
namespace AppBundle\Classes\CartFunctions;

class CartFunctions
{
    
    public function __construct()
    {
        // optional DI of other things if required
    }
    
    private function onlinecoupontrancation($params)
    {
        $foo = true;
        // whatever you want to do

        return $foo;
    }
}
```

Create this as a service, [instructions here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html)
Something like;

## app/config/services.yml

```
services:
    cart.functions:
        class:        AppBundle\CartFunctions
        arguments:    []
```

So in your controllers;

```
public function cartAction($params)
{
    // other stuff ...
    $cartFunctions = $this->get('cart.functions');
    $foo = $cartFunctions->onlinecoupontrancation($params);
}
```

Comment: onlinecoupontrancation function is using  other cartcontroller function.

Comment: @NituDhaka, I would put all functions relations to cart in the service class, then call functions from this class only. If the other function your are refering too is only for the cart functions then put that in the class, else return the data you need and keep processing as required